# Can this daily inventory balance calculation on bigquery be improved

Tags: google-bigquery

i came up with the following query to calculate inventory balances per day. The query works and gives me the expected results but it takes over 200 seconds to run on a subset of the transaction table with about 2mio rows.
Being new to bigquery i am wondering if there is a better/more efficient way to do this?

The code with some sample data is below.
Thanks in advance for any thoughts or tips.

```
#### Generate a continuous date range
WITH days AS 
  (
  SELECT day
  FROM UNNEST(
    GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(DATE('2011-01-01'), CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) AS day
  ),

#### Transactional information of inventory movements. Simple example
movements AS  
  (
  SELECT 1 AS ItemID
        ,1 AS Location
        ,DATE('2017-12-01') AS TransactionDate
        ,0 AS Quantity
        UNION ALL SELECT 1, 1, DATE('2017-12-03'), 10
        UNION ALL SELECT 1, 1, DATE('2017-12-06'), 100
        UNION ALL SELECT 1, 1, DATE('2017-12-12'), 1000
  ),  

#### Calculate cumulative sum for each item and location based on the transaction date
cumsum AS
  (
  SELECT ItemID
        ,TransactionDate
        ,Location
        ,SUM(Quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY ItemID, Location ORDER BY TransactionDate ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) as cumulative_quantity
  FROM movements
  ),  

#### Cross join with the date range to backfill cumulative values for each day
#### This will return multiple lines for a day when there are multiple transaction date balances
cross_sum AS
  (
  SELECT m.ItemID
        ,m.Location
        ,d.day
        ,m.TransactionDate
        ,m.cumulative_quantity
  FROM days d
  CROSS JOIN cumsum m
  WHERE m.TransactionDate <= d.day
  ),

#### Get just one line per day, based on the latest transaction date
filtered AS
  (
  SELECT ItemID
      ,Location
      ,CAST (day AS datetime) AS BalanceDate
      ,ARRAY_AGG(cumulative_quantity ORDER BY TransactionDate DESC LIMIT 1) AS InventoryBalance
  FROM cross_sum
  GROUP BY 1,2,3
  )

#### Final result, flattened out
SELECT ItemID
      ,Location
      ,BalanceDate
      ,(SELECT SUM(InventoryBalance) FROM UNNEST(InventoryBalance) AS InventoryBalance) AS InventoryBalance
FROM filtered
ORDER BY 1,2,3
```

Comment: in `movements` table - do you have multiple entries for the same date, item and location? checking - because even though comments say it is transactional info  - but code assumes it is already grouped by item, location, date and example conforms to this. Please clarify

Comment: thanks for looking into it @MikhailBerlyant. Yes, the source table is in fact transactional and has multiple entries for the same date, item and location and the `movements` table is grouped on those attributes since we don't care about the individual intraday changes but just the total daily change. The examples reflect the data is grouped. Hope that clarifies it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i am wondering if there is a better/more efficient way to do this?

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

as you can see: `days`, `cumsum` and `cross_sum` are modified/optimized and the rest just eliminated. It has good potentials to be more efficient but needs to be tested on real data - so you should try and see if it is

```sql
#standardSQL
#### Transactional information of inventory movements. Simple example
WITH movements AS (
  SELECT 1 AS ItemID, 1 AS Location, DATE('2017-12-01') AS TransactionDate, 0 AS Quantity UNION ALL 
  SELECT 1, 1, DATE('2017-12-03'), 10 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 1, 1, DATE('2017-12-06'), 100 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 1, 1, DATE('2017-12-12'), 1000
), days AS (
  SELECT day, ItemID, Location
  FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY((SELECT MIN(TransactionDate) AS d FROM movements), CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) AS day
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT ItemID, Location FROM movements)
), cumsum AS (
  SELECT ItemID
        ,TransactionDate
        ,Location
        ,LEAD(TransactionDate) OVER(PARTITION BY ItemID, Location ORDER BY TransactionDate) AS NextTransactionDate
        ,SUM(Quantity) OVER(PARTITION BY ItemID, Location ORDER BY TransactionDate ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS cumulative_quantity
  FROM movements
), cross_sum AS (
  SELECT d.ItemID
        ,d.Location
        ,d.day AS BalanceDate
        ,m.cumulative_quantity
  FROM days d
  JOIN cumsum m
  ON d.day >= IFNULL(m.TransactionDate, d.day) 
  AND d.day < IFNULL(m.NextTransactionDate, CURRENT_DATE())
)
SELECT ItemID
  ,Location
  ,BalanceDate
  ,cumulative_quantity
FROM cross_sum
ORDER BY 1,2,3
```

result is

```sql
ItemID  Location    BalanceDate    cumulative_quantity   
1         1         2017-12-01     0     
1         1         2017-12-02     0     
1         1         2017-12-03     10    
1         1         2017-12-04     10    
1         1         2017-12-05     10    
1         1         2017-12-06     110   
1         1         2017-12-07     110   
1         1         2017-12-08     110   
1         1         2017-12-09     110   
1         1         2017-12-10     110   
1         1         2017-12-11     110   
1         1         2017-12-12     1110  
1         1         2017-12-13     1110  
1         1         2017-12-14     1110  
1         1         2017-12-15     1110
```

Comment: Thank you Mikhail. The query above actually took forever when running on real data. i think it is missing a couple of `where` conditions on `Location` and `ItemID` in `cross_sum`: `AND d.Location = m.Location AND d.ItemID = m.ItemID`
After that the query returns correct results in about 60s so quite an improvement.

Comment: Also a follow up question, would it be possible to extend this to also calculate `date_diff` between `TransactionDate` and `day` for each of the dates? Basically to get the age of a particular transaction. Thank you very much again.

Comment: @PowdyPowPow - i think it is sure possible. But comments does not allow to provide answer. If you can post new question with all respective `new` details - we will try to answer

Comment: hi Mikhail. thank you i was actually able to figure it out, i was over complicating it in my head initially. putting `date_diff` into the `cross_sum` was all that was needed to get what i was after. thanks again for your help.

Comment: perfect! nice job! :o)